# Clock not updating every second using moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

First time using `moment.js` and I am struggling to implement a clock to show the time in CET and PST. My code is as follows:

```
function cetClock() {
    var cet = moment.tz("Europe/London");
    var today = new Date(cet);
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkCetTime(m);
    s = checkCetTime(s);
    $rootScope.cetTime =  h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    var t = setTimeout(cetClock, 300);
}
function checkCetTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}

cetClock()
```

---

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <p>CET: {{$root.cetTime}}</p>
</div>
```

The issue I have is that the time in the view is only being updated every 4-5 seconds. If I log the `h`, `m`, `s` within the function, it shows every 500 milliseconds the time being updated.

***Question***

Why is the clock in the viiew failing to update every second?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `$timeout` instead of `setTimeout` which will automatically trigger a digest cycle.

Comment: Ahhhhh. Frigging simple. Thank you. I will mark your answer correct when I can